# how to close an element upon the click of another element

Tags: javascript

I want each element to close upon the click of the "x" icon using pure javascript. i'm actually new to javascript so i am trying some stuffs out. Below is my code and what i have been able to do.

I want each element to close upon the click of the "x" icon.

```js
var closeBtnTask = document.querySelectorAll(".times");
for (var i = 0; i < closeBtnTask.length; i++) {
  closeBtnTask[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var panel = document.querySelectorAll(".taskpanel");
    for (var x = 0; x < taskpanel.length; x++) {
      Things[x].style.display = "none";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.task-box {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.task-wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

ul.mytask {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

ul.mytask li {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 34px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.mytask span {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="task-box">
  <div class="task-wrapper">
    <ul class="mytask">
      <li class="taskpanel">First Task <span><i class="fa fa-close times"></i></span></li>
      <li class="taskpanel">Second Task <span><i class="fa fa-close times"></i></span></li>
      <li class="taskpanel">Third Task <span><i class="fa fa-close times"></i></span></li>
      <li class="taskpanel">Fourth Task <span><i class="fa fa-close times"></i></span></li>
      <li class="taskpanel">Fifth Task <span><i class="fa fa-close times"></i></span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a missing `,` in you code here `addEventListener("click"function()`. And what is `Things`.

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to add a comma to make it run

Comment: You also want to change `Things` to `taskpanel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delegate in plain JS too

```js
document.querySelector(".mytask").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  let tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches(".fa-close")) tgt.closest("li").style.display="none";
})
```

```css
.task-box {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.task-wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

ul.mytask {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

ul.mytask li {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 34px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.mytask span {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="task-box">
  <div class="task-wrapper">
    <ul class="mytask">
      <li class="taskpanel">First Task <span><i class="fa fa-close times"></i></span></li>
      <li class="taskpanel">Second Task <span><i class="fa fa-close times"></i></span></li>
      <li class="taskpanel">Third Task <span><i class="fa fa-close times"></i></span></li>
      <li class="taskpanel">Fourth Task <span><i class="fa fa-close times"></i></span></li>
      <li class="taskpanel">Fifth Task <span><i class="fa fa-close times"></i></span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code was just a bit wrong, I fixed it here
https://jsfiddle.net/L81t9ym6/

```
var closeBtnTask = document.querySelectorAll(".times");
for (var i = 0; i < closeBtnTask.length; i++) {
  closeBtnTask[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var panel = document.querySelectorAll(".taskpanel");
    for (var x = 0; x < panel.length; x++) {
      panel[x].style.display = "none";
    }
  });
}
```

Note: this closes EVERY element when you click ANY x, rather than just the element that the click happened on.

edit

here's the code for closing JUST the panel you clicked

```
var closeBtnTask = document.querySelectorAll(".times");
for (var i = 0; i < closeBtnTask.length; i++) {
  closeBtnTask[i].addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
    var tp = ev.target.closest('.taskpanel');
    tp.style.display = "none";
  });
}
```

I didn't know that javascript has a native `.closest` method now, that's useful! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Comment: Thanks @TKoL i tried your code and it works like magic. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can also delegate in plain JS - see my answer

Answer (score -4):

use this Javascript 
working demo is here https://jsfiddle.net/Lg7bjr3k/

```
$('.times').click(function(){
$(this).parent().parent().hide();
})
```

Comment: he said 'pure javascript' in the question. I don't think he wants jquery.